Collision of structures names between C++ and C library
I have a C shared library that define structures, already defined in a C++ main project (same name but not same content). I am not allowed to modify the structures names on both sides and cannot also wrap the conflicting structures with a namespace in the C++ project.
So, i have tried to build a small C++ wrapper library (it could actually be header only) around the C library using a namespace but at some point, i need to expose the C structures in the C++ codebase :
// wrapper.h
#ifndef WRAPPER
#define WRAPPER

namespace Wrapper
{
// if the extern declaration is outside the namespace,
// i have conflicts on structures names 
extern "C" {
    #include "myCLibHeader.h" // includes <math.h>
}

// functions from the C library :
// Data1, Data2, Data3 are typedef for C structures
// How can i expose them without conflicting with the C++ code base ?
void foo(Data1 *d1, Data2 *d2);
void bar(Data3 *d3);
// ... some more


}

#endif

The C library has a single header, including <math.h> and this leads to multiple compilation errors such as :

In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/math.h:36:0, [build]
from /path/to/myCLibHeader.h:12, [build]                  from
/path/to/wrapper.h:10, [build]                  from
/path/to/wrapper.cpp:1: [build] /usr/include/c++/7/cmath:83:11: error:
‘::acos’ has not been declared [build]    using ::acos;

And there are many more errors with asin, atan2 and so on ...
If i move the extern declaration outside the namespace, then i get rid of those compilation errors, but then i have other errors related to conflicts on structures names because some of them are already defined in the C++ global namespace.
How can i solve this ?
Thank you

What happens if you put #include <math.h> before the namespace Wrapper?

Hacks aside, this sounds like you are intentionally violating the One Definition Rule. Any solution will be fragile.

@MSalters I know but i am stuck between a C legacy library and a C++ project. It seems to me that wrapping the C functions and structures inside a namespace is the less fragile solution i have. But i don't see any caveats with it unless you have something else in mind ?

@IanAbbott It actually solves the problem (i also had to #include <stdlib.h>) but why ?

It likely solves the problem because math.h has an include guard - and so the 2nd time it's included (from inside of that namespace) the content is skipped.

"But why?". Because beforehand the math functions were being declared in namespace Wrapper,
so e.g. Wrapper::acos, leaving your code outside the namespace making references to
undeclared (global) ::acos, etc. Now you are declaring them in global namespace. It
doesn't matter if myCLibHeader.h still includes math.h because it's include-gaurded
and won't be included twice.

I'm with @MSalters, in that hacks could come back to bite you.    Are you limited to what you can rebuild?, ie. are there existing C and C++ libraries that cannot be rebuilt?   If you can rebuild the C++, then you could move global types into a namespace and add using directives or using declarations - the project should continue to compile and you won't risk ODR violations.

It's a hack in that it's relying on the compiler implementing #include <math.h> as a fairly normal header file inclusion with include guards, rather than doing something magical with it, as it is allowed to.

@IanAbbott Ok, it's hack indeed but probably the best i can do in my current context. Thanks for your comment anyway, and if you intend to turn it into an answer i will mark it as accepted.

I think the most robust solution is NOT to make this header-only. Instead, the .cpp file should include the legacy C header, unwrapped. The wrapper header declares, but does not define struct Wrapper::Data1 etc.
The lack of a definition is not a problem. That's because the wrapper header only declares void Wrapper::foo(Wrapper::Data1 *d1, Wrapper::Data2 *d2). The .cpp file implements Wrapper::foo by calling ::foo(reinterpret_cast<::Data1*>(d1), reinterpret_cast<::Data2*>(d2)).
Now your existing C++ codebase only sees namespace Wrapper, but not the C include. The wrapper implementation sees the C include, but not your existing C++ code. The wrapper will see <math.h> but there it's included correctly at global scope.

Yes indeed but if the wrapper header only declare and does not define struct Wrapper::Data1, then how this structure can be instancied by the C++ side outside of the wrapper ? Those structs are parameters types for the C library functions (in the real code, they have a lot of fields as this part of C-code is mainly auto-generated)

@kzsnyk: You'll need to create factory methods in the wrapper.
